# Google Calendar API use Google Pub/Sub instead of HTTP Push notifications

Tags: google-api, google-cloud-pubsub, google-api-client, google-api-console

The current method seems to require opening up to the public a URL from which to receive a push notification: https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/push

Other Google technologies, like gmail (https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users/watch) works that we can specify a PubSub topic and then just subscribe.

This doesn't require me to open up a port externally, and also make easier localhost testing.

1. Is there any way to have a similar "PubSub to a topic" approach?
2. Is there any way to simplify localhost testing?